# How to retrieve SharedPreferences values in the SettingsActivity?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Here is some of the code in my custom-made `public class Preferences` that stores and retrieves values correctly in SharedPreferences:

```
public static final String DIR_SP_FILTERS = "filters";
public static final String KEY_SP_FILTERS_LIST = "flist";
public static final String DEFAULT_FILTERS = "1111110";
private static SharedPreferences f_sP;

public static void setUpPrefs(Context context, MapDisplay myMap) {
    // Load filter preferences
    f_sP = context.getSharedPreferences(DIR_SP_FILTERS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String masterFilters = f_sP.getString(KEY_SP_FILTERS_LIST, "");
    Menu menu = MainActivity.menu;

    if(masterFilters.length() != 0) {

        for(int i = 0; i < masterFilters.length(); i++) {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(masterFilters.charAt(i) + "");

            // Dans l'ordre du menu!
            switch(i) {
                case 0: // Feu
                    MapDisplay.feuFilter = filterTypeBtn(value, menu.findItem(R.id.cB_fire));
                case 1: // Eau
                    MapDisplay.eauFilter = filterTypeBtn(value, menu.findItem(R.id.cB_water));
                case 2: // Terrain
                    MapDisplay.terrainFilter = filterTypeBtn(value, menu.findItem(R.id.cB_terrain));
                case 3: // Météo
                    MapDisplay.meteoFilter = filterTypeBtn(value, menu.findItem(R.id.cB_meteo));
                case 4: // MZ
                    MapDisplay.showMonitoredZones = filterTypeBtn(value, menu.findItem(R.id.cB_zones));
                case 5: // UserPins
                    MapDisplay.showUserPins = filterTypeBtn(value, menu.findItem(R.id.cB_users));
                case 6: // Histo
                    MapDisplay.historiqueFilter = filterTypeBtn(value, menu.findItem(R.id.cB_histo));
            }
        }
    } else {
        // If first time launching app: initialize default filter string
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = f_sP.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_SP_FILTERS_LIST, DEFAULT_FILTERS);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

The most important part of the code here, for you guys, I believe are the constants declared at the beginning, which represent the names of the folders and sub-folders where I am saving information.

The set up `SharedPreferences` are working fine and I made sure that the specified values can be retrieved after the application is closed, and that modification from user input are saved properly (I won't show these methods to keep the thing simple).

I then proceeded to get AndroidStudio to automatically generate a SettingsActivity for me and wanted to add the possibility for the user to at least see the content of this String he is saving in memory ("1111110").

I thus added this to my `SettingsActivity.java`:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class FiltersPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_monitored_zones);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(Preferences.DIR_SP_FILTERS));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(Preferences.KEY_SP_FILTERS_LIST)););
    }
// ...
}
```

And made sure to add my Fragment in this list:

```
protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
    return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || GeneralPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || DataSyncPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || NotificationPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || FiltersPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName); // here
}
```

Notice those two important lines which I believe is my culprit:

```
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(Preferences.DIR_SP_FILTERS));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(Preferences.KEY_SP_FILTERS_LIST)););
```

They are using this method which was already defined when I generated the Activity:

```
private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

    // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
    // current value.
    sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
}
```

I did add my Fragment into the `pref_headers.xml` file, and created my `pref_filters.xml` (mostly copy-pasting from another `pref_*.xml` since I am still unsure how to deal with this):

```
<SwitchPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="example_switch"
    android:summary="@string/pref_description_social_recommendations"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_social_recommendations" />

<!-- NOTE: EditTextPreference accepts EditText attributes. -->
<!-- NOTE: EditTextPreference's summary should be set to its value by the activity code. -->
<EditTextPreference
    android:capitalize="words"
    android:defaultValue="@string/pref_default_display_name"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:key="filters"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_display_name" />

<!-- NOTE: Hide buttons to simplify the UI. Users can touch outside the dialog to
     dismiss it. -->
<!-- NOTE: ListPreference's summary should be set to its value by the activity code. -->
<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="-1"
    android:entries="@array/pref_example_list_titles"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_example_list_values"
    android:key="example_list"
    android:negativeButtonText="@null"
    android:positiveButtonText="@null"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_add_friends_to_messages" />
```

My understanding is that the key to making this all work is to use the `android:key="filters"` properly by making it point to the proper folder or sub-folder as listed in the two lines that I showed earlier (`bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(Preferences.DIR_SP_FILTERS));`), but I'm unsure what value to use there to get what I want.

Thanks for helping ! :)